DuckDB prepared statement list
I wanted a parameterized query using which I wanted to fetch persons dynamically:
import duckdb
query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id IN(?)"
duckdb.execute(query, [[4,5,6]])

This is raising the exception
ConversionException: Conversion Error: Unimplemented type for cast (BIGINT -> INTEGER[])

How to go about it?

What's unclear about the error? What did you expect duckdb.execute(query, [[4,5,6]]) to do?

I wanted the query to be "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id IN(4,5,6);" generated at runtime.

The correct way to do this currently is to use IN(SELECT UNNEST(?))
import duckdb
lst = [1,2,3,4]
res = duckdb.execute("select * from ( VALUES (5),(3),(6),(2),(7) ) t(i) where i IN(SELECT UNNEST(?))", [lst]).fetchall()
print(res)
#[(3,), (2,)]

This might be improved in the future however

I'm not so familiar with DuckDB prepared statements, but pretty sure you shoul to use next code:
import duckdb

options = [4,5,6]
query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id IN(%s)" % ','.join(map(lambda x: '?', options))

duckdb.execute(query, options)


Thanks, but the main reason for the list is the length is dynamic and determined at runtime.

Look the updated answer
